# How to screenshot a certain frame and send it to a specific email address?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I screenshot a certain frame in ActionScript 3 Flash and send it to a specific email address?

Also, when I researched sample projects, it provided external as, Then.. How would I call it from a frame?

I'm creating a Cake Customizer. When the cake is done, I want to screen capture it and send it directly to an email.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project a year or so ago where I was creating a multi-touch table application to go in a sales center for a new condo building. One of the functions was a customer being able to customize a floorplan with little furniture graphics and send it to themselves via email. I accomplished this using Adobe's PNGEncoder(https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) and Coltware's airxmail (http://flex.coltware.com/as3-flex-air/airxmail/).

For using external AS from a frame, you can use (as pointed out in MasterRoro's answer)

```
include 'external_file.as';
```

You could also include the code in a class and it to the source path of your FLA. To do this, you go to Edit > Preferences. Click "Actionscript" category. Then click "Actionscript 3.0 settings". In the "Source Path" box, use the plus button to add individual AS files (or the folder button to have Actionscript search an entire folder for source AS files). Then you'll be able to create a new instance of the class within the frame.

For instance, to use the MailMain.as class below, you could save it to an AS file called MailMan.as and add it to the source path as outlined above. Then on the frame you can simply create a new instance of it:

```
var mail:MailMan = new MailMan();
mail.sendImageFile(...)
```

Here is the code I would use to save an image of the floorplan. When you provide the BitmapData, its constructor asks for the width and height of the data. Here you can provide cake.width and cake.height or something similar.

```
        var theBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(1620, 1080));
        log("Drawing floorplan");
        theBitmap.bitmapData.draw(this);

        log("Saving floorplan image to desktop");
        var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(theBitmap.bitmapData);
        var savePoint:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(floorplan.model + "_floorplan" + Math.random()*10000 + ".png");
        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
        try
        {
            fs.open(savePoint, FileMode.WRITE);
            fs.writeBytes(ba);
            fs.close();
            log("Floorplan saved!");

            var mailman:MailMan = new MailMan();
            mailman.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_SENT_OK, fpSent);
            mailman.sendImageFile("", fpEmailDial.getTo(), savePoint);
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            log("Error occurred while trying to save image file");
        }
```

Here's the class I created for sending email. It includes examples for sending images and just a plain text email. Note that SQLHelper and ResourceManager are my proprietary classes but their functionality is evident.

```
public class MailMan extends EventDispatcher
{
    private var sender:SMTPSender;
    private var sql:SQLHelper;

    public function MailMan()
    {
        sql = new SQLHelper(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("mtt-persistent.db"));

        initSender();
    }

    public function initSender():void
    {
        log("Initializing Sender");
        sender = new SMTPSender();

        //this is the info for the host email from which the email is sent.
        //you might want to create an email such as "noreply@example.com" to act as the host

        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.HOST,"smtp.gmail.com");
        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PORT,465);
        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,5000);
        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.ENABLE_BUFFER,true);

        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.AUTH,true);
        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.USERNAME,"noreply.salescenter@gmail.com");
        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PASSWORD,"salescenterpassword");

        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.SOCKET_OBJECT, new TLSSocket());

        log("Sender parameters set");

        //  STARTTLS Handler
        //sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_START_TLS,startTlsHandler);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_CONNECTION_FAILED, onConnFail);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_AUTH_NG, authFail);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_AUTH_OK, onAuthOK);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_ACCEPT_DATA, onAccData);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_NOT_SUPPORT_ESMTP, onNotSuppESMTP);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_SENT_OK, onSent);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_NOOP_OK, noopOK);
        sender.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.SMTP_COMMAND_ERROR, onCommandError);

        function onAccData(e:SMTPEvent):void
        {
            log("Data Accepted");
        }
        function onAuthOK(e:SMTPEvent):void
        {
            log("Account authorized successfully");
        }
        function onConnFail(e:SMTPEvent):void
        {
            log("SMTP Connection FAIL");
        }
        function authFail(e:SMTPEvent):void
        {
            log("SMTP Auth NG");
        }


    }

    public function sendPic(salesEmail:String, toEmail:String, picID:String)
    {
        log("Sending image:" + picID + ":");
        var contentType:ContentType = ContentType.MULTIPART_MIXED;
        var mimeMsg:MimeMessage = new MimeMessage(contentType);

        var salespersonReq:Array = sql.select("salespeople", new Array(new SQLParam("email", salesEmail)));

        if (salespersonReq != null)
        {
            var salespersonInfo:Object = salespersonReq[0];
            var salesFirstname:String = salespersonInfo.firstname as String;
            var salesLastname:String = salespersonInfo.lastname as String;

            var from:INetAddress = new INetAddress();
            from.personal = salesFirstname + " " + salesLastname;
            from.address = salesEmail;
        }
        else
        {
            var from:INetAddress = new INetAddress();
            from.personal = "Sales Center";
            from.address = "salescenteremail@gmail.com";
        }
        mimeMsg.setFrom(from);
        mimeMsg.setReplyTo(from);

        var to:INetAddress = new INetAddress();
        to.address = toEmail;
        mimeMsg.addRcpt(RecipientType.TO, to);

        mimeMsg.setSubject("Your image");
        mimeMsg.setTextBody("Your image");

        var textPart:MimeTextPart = new MimeTextPart();
        textPart.contentType.setParameter("charset", "UTF-8");
        textPart.transferEncoding = "8bit";
        textPart.setText("Please find attached the image you sent yourself.");
        mimeMsg.addChildPart(textPart);

        var filePart:MimeImagePart = new MimeImagePart();
        filePart.contentType.setMainType("image");
        filePart.contentType.setSubType("png");

        //here I'm grabbing the image that was encoded into a png and saved to the filesystem
        var imageFile:File = (ResourceManager.getInstance().getResourceByID("email_" + picID) as AssetLoader).origFile;
        filePart.setAttachementFile(imageFile, imageFile.name);
        mimeMsg.addChildPart(filePart);

        sender.send(mimeMsg);
        //sender.close();
    }

    public function sendImageFile(salesEmail:String, toEmail:String, imageFile:File)
    {
        log("Sending image:" + imageFile.name);
        var contentType:ContentType = ContentType.MULTIPART_MIXED;
        var mimeMsg:MimeMessage = new MimeMessage(contentType);

        var salespersonReq:Array = sql.select("salespeople", new Array(new SQLParam("email", salesEmail)));
        var salespersonInfo:Object = salespersonReq[0];

        var salesFirstname:String = salespersonInfo.firstname as String;
        var salesLastname:String = salespersonInfo.lastname as String;

        var from:INetAddress = new INetAddress;
        from.personal = salesFirstname + " " + salesLastname;
        from.address = salesEmail;
        mimeMsg.setFrom(from);
        mimeMsg.setReplyTo(from);

        var to:INetAddress = new INetAddress();
        to.address = toEmail;
        mimeMsg.addRcpt(RecipientType.TO, to);

        mimeMsg.setSubject("Your floorplan");
        mimeMsg.setTextBody("Your floorplan");

        var textPart:MimeTextPart = new MimeTextPart();
        textPart.contentType.setParameter("charset", "UTF-8");
        textPart.transferEncoding = "8bit";
        textPart.setText("Please find attached the floorplan you sent yourself.");
        mimeMsg.addChildPart(textPart);

        var filePart:MimeImagePart = new MimeImagePart();
        filePart.contentType.setMainType("image");
        filePart.contentType.setSubType("png");
        filePart.setAttachementFile(imageFile, imageFile.name);
        mimeMsg.addChildPart(filePart);

        sender.send(mimeMsg);
        //sender.close();
    }

    public function sendPlainText():void
    {
        log("Sending plain text message");
        var contentType:ContentType = ContentType.MULTIPART_MIXED;
        var mimeMsg:MimeMessage = new MimeMessage(contentType);

        var from:INetAddress = new INetAddress();
        from.personal = "Ima Sample";
        from.address = "youremail@gmail.com";

        mimeMsg.setFrom(from);
        mimeMsg.setReplyTo(from);
        var toAddr:INetAddress = new INetAddress("toemail@gmail.com","Kiks");
        mimeMsg.addRcpt(RecipientType.TO,toAddr);
        // set mail subject
        mimeMsg.setSubject("Hello Airxmail");
        mimeMsg.setTextBody("this is another test, but with attachments");

        var textPart:MimeTextPart = new MimeTextPart();
        textPart.contentType.setParameter("charset", "UTF-8");
        textPart.transferEncoding = "8bit";
        textPart.setText("This is the text of the message");
        mimeMsg.addChildPart(textPart);


        var filePart:MimeImagePart = new MimeImagePart();
        filePart.contentType.setMainType("image");
        filePart.contentType.setSubType("png");
        filePart.setAttachementFile(File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("testMail.png"), "testMail.png");
        mimeMsg.addChildPart(filePart);


        sender.send(mimeMsg);
        sender.close();
    }

    protected function onCommandError(event:SMTPEvent):void
    {
        log("A Command error has occurred");
    }

    protected function noopOK(event:Event):void
    {
        log("NOOP OK");
    }

    protected function onSent(event:SMTPEvent):void
    {
        log("MESSAGE SENT!");
        dispatchEvent(new SMTPEvent(SMTPEvent.SMTP_SENT_OK));
    }

    protected function onNotSuppESMTP(event:SMTPEvent):void
    {
        log("ESMTP Not Supported"); 
    }

    public function startTlsHandler(event:SMTPEvent):void
    {
        log("TLS Handler Started");
        var sock:Socket = event.socket as Socket;

        var tls:TLSSocket = new TLSSocket();
        sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.SOCKET_OBJECT,tls);
        tls.startTLS(sock,"smtp.gmail.com");
        sendPlainText();
    }


    private function log(msg:String):void
    {
        WOWLogger.logMsg("MailMan", msg);
        trace("[MailMan] " + msg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely capture an image and save it into your file system. But to mail it somewhere you'd have to use PHP or some other serverside script to be able to manage that.

First, to use the actionscript from an external file, use
`include 'filename.as'`

To save an image, you need a JPG or PNG encoder from Adobe, you can find the codebase that contains those classes here:

https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

Then, once they are in your build path, import those classes (PNGEncoder or JPGEncoder) depending on what format you want to save to.

`import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;`

Next, you're going to need to draw the image of the cake to a `BitmapData` object. You can draw the whole stage but if you just want to draw the container with the cake in it, that's fine too.

```
//draw the cake into a bitmap data
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(cake.width, cake.height);
bmd.draw(cake);


var imageFile:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode( bmd);

//This opens a save prompt allowing you to save your image to the file system
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
fileRef.save(imageFile);
```

As for mailing it... someone correct me if I'm wrong but it's impossible to do that alone with actionscript.